# Automate Web Applications -parsing HTML Data

Tags: html, web-applications, automation, html-parsing

I just want to automate a web application, where that application parses the HTML page and pulls all the HTML Tags inner text based on some condition like if we have a tag called Span Example has given whose class="spanclass_1"
 This is span tag... 
which has particular class id. so that app parses and pulls that span into it.

And here the main pain area is, I should not use the developer code to automate that same parsing the HTML. 
I want to automate that parsing done correctly, simply by using the parsed data which is shown in UI.

Any help, would be great.

Appreciating your time reading this.

(Note span tag is not shown)

Thanks buddies.

Answer (score 0):

[image]not enough details.

is this html page just a file in local filesystem on it is internet webpage?

do u have access to pages? can u modify it ? if answer yes, that just add javascript to page which will extract data and post to server.

if answer not, than it depends on language u use to programm.

Find good framework to parse html. load page parse it and extract data. Several situation can be there.

```
Worse scenario  - page generated on client side using js.
Best scenario - page is in xhtml mode( u are lucky. any xml parser will help to build dom and extract data)
So so - page is simple html format (try several html parser to find most suitable for u)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited your comment with my UI Pic which I want to automate, where those parsed content should be verified automatically. [ Sorry to post in your comment as I don't have enough reputation to post the images] thanks.